# same value in dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I m mapping data that come from service with using dictionary [String: String]. I collect them dictionary array. For example, if their parent ids are the same, I want to add their values by array value.

```
["ParentId": "1","Value": "["Giyim","Aksesuar","Ayakkabı"]"]
```

It is also the reason I don't know parent id sometimes on the left sometimes on the right in photo

Here is my code and its output.

```swift
struct Categories {

    let parentId: String
    let values: [String]

}

                for result in results {

                    if result?.parentCategoryId != "" {
                        
                        for docId in self.docIds {
                            
                            if result?.parentCategoryId == docId {
                                
                                //print(result?.name)
                                var values = [String]()
                                values.append(result?.name ?? "")
                                
                                self.newCat.append(Categories(parentId: docId, values: values))
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
```

[image: edited picture]

Comment: Should "Value" end up being a `String` representation of an array (eg comma separated values), or do you actually want it to be `[String]`? Have you considered using `structs` instead of dictionaries? Also, might it make sense to make your structure a Dictionary keyed by `ParentId` instead of an array of dictionaries?

Comment: Regarding the order it prints in, `Dictionary` does not have an inherent order, so that printing behavior is expected.

Comment: @jnpdx ok I m gonna try with struct so How can I collect those whose parentids have the same values, in the same value array. I have created a struct that has a one string and string array

Comment: I edited the question to apply some sane formatting. You should do that yourself next time.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to reflect what you have and then we can go from there?

Comment: I think you're just looking for [`Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init).

Comment: Also, isn't it strange that you're adding items to a dictionary called `emptyDic`, which after adding items to it ... won't be empty? 

Comment: @Alexander sorry I'm a little nervous about this problem I can't ask many questions I am new here
I will check Dictionary.init (grouping: by) thank you

Comment: @jnpdx I added struct

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the `struct` approach, you could do something like this (you'll need to adapt it to your code, but that should be straightforward):

```
struct Categories {
    let parentId: String
    var values: [String] //notice this needs to be a var, not a let
}

func addItem(categories : inout [Categories], docId: String, name: String) {
        if let index = categories.firstIndex(where: { $0.parentId == docId }) {
            categories[index].values.append(name)
        } else {
            categories.append(Categories(parentId: docId, values: [name]))
        }
}

func addValues() {
  var categories = [Categories]()
  addItem(categories: &categories, docId: "4", name: "Test1")
  addItem(categories: &categories, docId: "1", name: "Test")
  addItem(categories: &categories, docId: "4", name: "Test2")
  addItem(categories: &categories, docId: "4", name: "Test3")
  print(categories)

  //in your code, it'll look more like:
  // addItem(categories: &self.newCat, docId: docId, name: result?.name ?? "")
}
```

Which yields this:

```
[
  StackOverflowPlayground.Categories(parentId: "4", values: ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]), 
  StackOverflowPlayground.Categories(parentId: "1", values: ["Test"])
]
```

I still wonder whether you maybe just want a `Dictionary` that is keyed by the `parentId`, but not knowing your use case, it's hard to say.

Comment: I will adapt it to my code thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

As far as I understand from the description you want to map some service data structure to a dictionary where **key is parentId** and **value is an array** of some items referred to parentId.

I believe your problem comes from a misunderstanding of the concept of [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) as a data structure.
`[String: String]` is dictionary where keys and their associated values are of *String* type. For example:

```
["firstKey": "firsthValue", "secondKey": "secondValue", ...]
```

That means **you cannot store associated values of String and Array types in the same dictionary**, as you already told the compiler you would like to store only strings.

> It is also the reason I don't know parent id sometimes on the left sometimes on the right in photo

This is because key-value pairs are stored in the dictionary without order. This is how dictionaries work :) I'd strongly recommend reading some short [official](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) materials to get used to them.

- New Swift 5.4 version has a new OrderedDictionary data structure, where keys are ordered, but there is absolutely 100500% no reason to use it for your problem*

#### Possible solutions

In your case i would suggest either use some struct:

```
struct SomeData {
    let parentID: Int
    var values: [String]
}

var storage: [SomeData] // alternative to emptyDic

// Filling storage with data from service
for result in inputData {
    // search for SomeData with required id, add value
    // OR create SomeData if there is no such id in array yet
}
```

**OR** [personally this appeals to me more]

Store data in `[String: [String]]` dictionary, where the key is parentID and the associated value is an array of values.
The algorithm of filling this dictionary is pretty the same:

1. You add new key-value pair for every new parentID
2. You append new values for parentIDs that are already in the dictionary.